# Multiple website tables within one mySql database

Tags: mysql

I have a question on whether it's wise or not to have a lot of different websites reading from one mysql database on a server, and only have prefixes eg pre_users to seperate the websites from one another different prefixes for different websites. One website may contain up to 20+tables. Or is there a better way to accomplish this. My reason behind this is the company I work for want to develop a system thats able to create websites in steps and this will then create a new db entry for every single site. Hope I make sense

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put a `website_id` column in each table instead of creating a new table for each website? The design you're proposing is *usually*, though not always, a poor one.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolute have to use unique database why don't you use a table SITES and link the others tables like that :

```
SITES (ID int, ...)
USERS (Site int, ...)
TABLE1 (Site int, ...)
TABLE2 (Site int, ...)
```